# CouchDB: Is it more efficient to use includeDocs, or return doc from view?

Tags: performance, couchdb

I'm new to CouchDB. We're going to have millions of documents in our database. I am wondering: is it more efficient to return the 'doc' object from the view, or return just the 'doc.id', and use '&include_docs=true'?

I'm guessing that returning 'doc.id' from the view will take up a lot less disk space for the view index, but might require an added call to the database to get the whole document. In this case, it's a decision between more speed (returning 'doc') or decreased disk space usage (returning 'doc.id').

Is this a correct assumption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the couchDB wiki https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API

> Note: include_docs will cause a single document lookup per returned view result row. This adds significant strain on the storage system if you are under high load or return a lot of rows per request. If you are concerned about this, you can emit the full doc in each row; this will increase view index time and space requirements, but will make view reads optimally fast.

So I'd say you're correct in your assumptions, the next step to consider is will you actually use the views to get all the matching documents or will you just look at a few matching documents at the time? This is interesting since couchDB will build the entire view and maintain it throughout updates even if you're just looking at a small section of it.

One other thing to consider is how large are the documents? If the documents are small there will be little diffrens in emitting them, but if they are large there will be a vast diffrence.

Comment: Thanks, Petter. The documents are not that big, so I think we will prefer speed over disk space usage.